# Persistence.xml file of EntityManagerFactory in a jar file

Tags: java, entitymanager

Is there any way to put content of persistence.xml file to the source code that calling EntityManagerFactory? I tried building a project that contain persistence.xml but when I call the it from another project I always get this error:

```
[PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named cassandra_pu]
```

I also extract the jar file to check whether the xml file is included or not, it;s included in the WEB-INF folder. To me it's really weird because the persistence.xml is already in the jar file, why it keeps asking for the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

The persistence.xml file must be in the root of your classpath. WEB-INF is not in the root of the class-path. If you want to put it in a .jar file, place it in WEB-INF/lib, if you want to have it outside a .jar file, place it in WEB-INF/classes. If you use JPA2 you no longer need that file.

Comment: I kept it in src/META-INF , when I tried as you said, I can't even run the project before building it. It said that Exception in thread "main" com.impetus.kundera.loader.PersistenceLoaderException: com.impetus.kundera.utils.InvalidConfigurationException: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml  file in the classpath